# list comprehension to split string and return string and its length

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I have a string and I wish to use list comprehension to print words with even number of letters by using a tuple (word, length) in my list comprehension. I tried something like this to return a list of tuples of words containing even number of letters:

```
sentence = 'If you dont actually care about collecting all the strings in a list using a list comprehension doesnt make much sense'

word_with_even_letters = [(word,len(word)) in sentence.split() if len(word)==0]
```

Actual Results:

> File "", line 2
>       word_with_even_letters = [(word,len(word)) in sentence.split() if len(word)==0]
>                                                                                     ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Expected results: The list word_with_even_letters should hold the following tuples:

```
(If,2)
(dont,4)
(actually,8)
(care,4)
(collecting,10)
(in,2)
(list,4)
(doesnt,6)
(make,4)
(much,4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `for` statement in a list-comprehension, and to check if a number is even don't test if `n == 0`, instead it's if `n % 2 == 0`:

```
sentence = 'If you dont actually care about collecting all the strings in a list using a list comprehension doesnt make much sense'

word_with_even_letters = [(word, len(word)) for word in sentence.split() if len(word) % 2 == 0]

print(word_with_even_letters)
```

Output:

```
[('If', 2), ('dont', 4), ('actually', 8), ('care', 4), ('collecting', 10), ('in', 2), ('list', 4), ('list', 4), ('doesnt', 6), ('make', 4), ('much', 4)]
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I had missed out the %2 and the for statement.

Answer (score 0):

A command is missing:

```
word_with_even_letters = [(word,len(word)) for word in sentence.split() if len(word)%2==0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence.split()
```

is an iterative, and you must use its items,
please change your code to this:

```
sentence = 'If you dont actually care about collecting all the strings in a list using a list comprehension doesnt make much sense'

word_with_even_letters = list((word,len(word)) for word in sentence.split() if len(word)%2==0)

print(word_with_even_letters)
```